# Using AutoMapper to map Wrapper<T> to T' by convention

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a service which wraps enum-values in a SafeEnum type, to enable addition of new enum values without breaking the contract.

Here's an example:

```
public class Customer
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public SafeEnum<CustomerType> Type { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public CustomerModelType Type { get; set; }
}
```

When mapping from Customer to CustomerModel using AutoMapper, is there a way to automatically map from `SafeEnum<T>` to `T'`, where `T` is the wrapped type and `T'` is the matching type in the model?

I know this can be fixed by configuring for each relevant enum-type, but I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: @zespri No, it is the model version of CustomerType, i.e. another enum type with the same or similar values. I have edited the example to reflect this, thanks for pointing it out. (the example is just an example, it doesn't reflect the real types I have)

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled with the same problem recently. From what i've gather there is no official support from Automapper for this kind of scenario (there's no mention of generic wrappers or anything similar on the documentation and i couldn't find any web resource with how to do it), but it can be accomplished with a little bit of work.

First you need to create a class that implements the `IObjectMapper` interface. This interface has two methods `IsMatch(ResolutionContext context)` and `Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper)`

When mapping two objects, the `IsMatch` method is used internally by Automapper to determine if a given instance of `IObjectMapper` can be used to map from  the source type to the destination type. On the `ResolutionContext` object you have the SourceType, DestinationType, SourceValue, DestinationValue, an instance of MappingEngine among other things that can help you determine if you can map the two types with your current mapper.

The Map method is responsible for the actual mapping between the two types.

So, on the `IsMatch` method you should check if the source or destination type are instances of your wrapper class. And then, on the `Map` method, when mapping from the wrapped value,  you could unwrap the value with reflection, and use the mapping engine provided on the ResolutionContext to map the unwrapped value to it's destination type, and then returning it.

Similarly, when mapping from any type to a wrapped type, you could get the type argument of the closed generic wrapper, use the mapping engine provided on the resolution context to map from the source type, to the type enclosed by your generic wrapper, and wrap the result on an instance of the wrapper class of the appropiate type.

Finally, you need to include this mapper when configuring your MappingEngine on the application startup  (This doesn't work with with the static method of the Mapper class, since you can't change the default mappers on it), like this:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationStore(new TypeMapFactory(), new IObjectMapper[] { new WrapperMapper()}.Union(MapperRegistry.Mappers));
        var engine = new MappingEngine(configuration);
```

The `MapperRegistry.Mappers` static property is a collection of all the default Automapper mappers. If you don't include these, you'll lose all the default functionality.

Finally, here's a working fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/vWmRiY

It'll probably need some work to adapt it to your particular use case, but the general idea is there. This could be used to wrap primitive types, complex types, or anything that is supported by automapper.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler solution "explained" [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/discussions/3981). Use implicit conversions!

Just the wrapper class should be something like:

```
public class ObjectWrapper<T>
{

    private T _property;
    
    public ObjectWrapper(T property) {
        _property = property;
    }

    public static implicit operator ObjectWrapper<T>(T value)
    {
        return new ObjectWrapper<T>(value);
    }

    public static explicit operator T(ObjectWrapper<T> myObject)
    {
        return myObject._property;
    }
}
```